# Batch File Live Title

Tags: batch-file, windows-xp, echo, title

I need to be able to change the title of batch A at the same time of execution of other parts of script.

i want to be able to have it say `Hello! world`. and `echo 1&2 simutaneously` and while the screen is switching between 1 and 2 i need the title to change from 2 to 3.

and please dont give me something like this.

```
echo Hello! world.
ping localhost 3 >nul
title 2
echo Hello! world. 1
ping localhost 3 >nul
title 3
echo Hello! world. 2
ping localhost 3 >nul
title 2
:loop
```

Thanks in advance to anyone with an answer that works!

Comment: What is not working with the code you posted? The title changes just fine, as expected.

Comment: yes it does but i want it to do the title change while it is also allowing me to type in the batch file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that in pure Batch.
Batch is a procedural language.

You could try writing a program in another language that can talk to the Windows API:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms682073(v=vs.85).aspx

You ***might*** be able to spawn a separate process that could get the Handle for your Console window and then change the title remotely.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with pure batch.
You only need a second thread, that can be started with `start /b`.

The expample code updates the current time in the title until the user press enter.

```
@echo off
REM *** Trampoline to call a label included in the filename
FOR /F "tokens=3 delims=:" %%L in ("%~0") DO goto :%%L

start "" /b cmd /c %~d0\:change_title:\..\%~pnx0

2> lock.tmp (
set /p "value=Enter Text: "
)

echo End of prog
exit /b

:change_title
2> NUL ( > lock.tmp ( break ) ) || (
    title Current time %time%
    ping localhost -n 2 > NUL
    goto :change_title
)

del lock.tmp
title Thread finished
exit /b
```